# What does "legacy fallback" mean when cabal is building packages?

Tags: haskell, build, cabal

When using `cabal` to build a Haskell package, it appears to mark some packages as `legacy fallback`:

```
$ cabal build
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-9.0.1 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - appar-0.1.8 (lib:appar) (requires build)
 - auto-update-0.1.6 (lib) (requires build)
 - base-compat-0.11.2 (lib) (requires build)
...
Building     base-orphans-0.8.4 (lib)
Building     appar-0.1.8 (all, legacy fallback)
Downloaded   memory-0.16.0
Downloading  cryptonite-0.29
Installing   base-orphans-0.8.4 (lib)
Downloaded   cryptonite-0.29
Downloading  some-1.0.3
...
```

You can see that for some libraries, they are specifically marked `(lib)`, but other libraries are marked `(all, legacy fallback)`.

What is the difference between these?  What does `legacy fallback` mean?

---

I am using `cabal-install` version 3.4.0.0:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.4.0.0
compiled using version 3.4.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took a dive in the source code. The error message comes form [here](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/174673d049dac94823db9e7470412ded95fe2e4d/cabal-install/src/Distribution/Client/ProjectBuilding.hs#L1081):

```hs
    dispname = case elabPkgOrComp pkg of
        ElabPackage _ -> prettyShow pkgid
            ++ " (all, legacy fallback)"
        ElabComponent comp -> prettyShow pkgid
            ++ " (" ++ maybe "custom" prettyShow (compComponentName comp) ++ ")"
```

So I started looking for places where `ElabPackage` is constructed. I found [this](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/873216ff5a62730b62c25dc8d1d3acc93974e0b1/cabal-install/src/Distribution/Client/ProjectPlanning.hs#L1648):

```hs
    elaborateSolverToPackage
        ...
      where
        ...
        elab1 = elab0 {
                elabUnitId = newSimpleUnitId pkgInstalledId,
                elabComponentId = pkgInstalledId,
                elabLinkedInstantiatedWith = Map.empty,
                elabPkgOrComp = ElabPackage $ ElaboratedPackage {..},
                elabModuleShape = modShape
            }
```

This in turn is used [here](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/873216ff5a62730b62c25dc8d1d3acc93974e0b1/cabal-install/src/Distribution/Client/ProjectPlanning.hs#L1331):

```hs
    elaborateSolverToComponents mapDep spkg@(SolverPackage _ _ _ deps0 exe_deps0)
        = case mkComponentsGraph (elabEnabledSpec elab0) pd of
           Right g -> do
            ...
            let not_per_component_reasons = why_not_per_component src_comps
            if null not_per_component_reasons
                then return comps
                else do checkPerPackageOk comps not_per_component_reasons
                        return [elaborateSolverToPackage spkg g $
                                comps ++ maybeToList setupComponent]
```

Now the `why_not_per_component` is very interesting as that function determines when to use the legacy fallback. It is defined [here](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/873216ff5a62730b62c25dc8d1d3acc93974e0b1/cabal-install/src/Distribution/Client/ProjectPlanning.hs#L1339):

```hs
        -- You are eligible to per-component build if this list is empty
        why_not_per_component g
            = cuz_buildtype ++ cuz_spec ++ cuz_length ++ cuz_flag ++ cuz_coverage
```

There in the code right below that we can see that it can be caused by these reasons:

- The build-type is Custom or Configure
- The cabal-version is less than 1.8
- There are no buildable components
- You passed the `--disable-per-component` flag.
- Program coverage is enabled

So for the `appar` library it is because the cabal-version is 1.6 which is lower than 1.8, see https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/appar/blob/v0.1.8/appar.cabal#L10.